# Update properties file with form values is not working

Tags: java

I am having a servlet where I am getting all the form values and storing it in a variable , in that servlet itself I am trying to update my properties file. But properties file is not getting updated. Can anyone tell me how can I access my form values and update my properties file.

Servlet file

```
  protected void doPost
(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name=request.getParameter("appName");
    String link=request.getParameter("appLink");
    String database=request.getParameter("appDB");
    String webServices=request.getParameter("appWebService");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("server_url.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("server_url.properties");
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_Links", link);
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_DataBase", database);
    props.store(outputStream , null);
    outputStream .close();
System.out.println(link);
System.out.println(database);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting parameters properly in your Servlet ?

Comment: Try flushing the stream before closing it: outputStream.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Close input stream first and then update properties.

```
    **in.close();**
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("server_url.properties");
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_Links", link);
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_DataBase", database);
```

Assuming you are getting link and database params correctly.

Comment: I am getting this exception `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`

Comment: Put it after `props.load(in);`